# How to use variables in SQL statement in Python using IN statement

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have dataframe with 2 cols, id and email. Now I want to write sql query to use in python which dynamically fetches only those emails which are present in `df['email']`.
The sql equivalent of this query will be something like this

```
select id, email from xdb where email in (email1, email2, ...);
```

But I want something like `df['email']`  instead of `(email1, email2, ...)`. How can I put a variable in place of writing all those email one by one?
And am using pandas `pd.read_sql` function to run the queries and mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
pd.read_sql(f"select id, email from xdb where email in {tuple(df.email.values)}", conn)
```